# OS-Specific Maven Profile is always activated

Tags: maven, maven-profiles

I'm trying to define a profile that is activated only in case two conditions fit:

- a special folder exists
- the correct operating system

  ```
  <profile>
      <id>test</id>
      <activation>
          <file>
              <exists>file</exists>
          </file>
          <os>
              <family>windows/unix/etc...</family>
          </os>
      </activation>
  </profile>
  ```

I tried to define it that way, but in case the operating system matches the profile is activated, even the folder does not exist. But I want to run some plugins in case the folder exists, in case a binary is required the operating system must match.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Maven JIRA, this is an open issue: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-4565

The comments for the above-linked issue point to a Maven extension that provides the functionality you are looking for: https://github.com/johnjcool/and-activation-profile-selector